YOCTO: Systemd services not enabled on boot
I'm using version 2.2 (morty) of Yocto and I'm struggling to get a couple of my services to be enabled on boot. This is my current setup:

I don't want all services to be enabled by default, so I've set SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE ?= disable.

I've installed the services in question to ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/. I've confirmed on boot that the services are present, just not enabled.

In my recipe where I install the service in question, I also have the line SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}_<machine_name> = "<service_name>.service <another-service>.service". There are multiple different machines that I compile for, and each machine requires a different service so each machine has a line like above with the appropriate service name.

I have another recipe which adds other unrelated services which have the exact same setup (install to the same place, adding the service to SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}_<machine_name> in the same way). These services are enabled as expected on first boot.


I've included a simplified version of the both recipes below. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stumped.
Recipe Whose Services Are Enabled on Boot:
SRC_URI_machine1 += "file://machine1/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules \
                 file://machine1/lib/systemd/system/button-off.service \
                 file://machine1/lib/systemd/system/machine1-startup.service \
                 file://machine1/etc/machine1/startup \
                 file://machine1/usr/bin/button_press_off.sh \
                 file://machine1/usr/bin/execstop.sh \
                "

SRC_URI_machine2 += "file://machine2/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules \
                    file://machine2/lib/systemd/system/button-off.service \
                    file://machine2/lib/systemd/system/machine2-startup.service \
                    file://machine2/etc/machine2/startup \
                    file://machine2/usr/bin/button_press_off.sh \
                    file://machine2/usr/bin/execstop.sh \
                    "

FILES_${PN} += "${bindir} ${sysconfdir} ${systemd_unitdir}/system ${base_libdir}"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}_machine1 =    "
                                button-off.service \
                                machine1-startup.service \
                                "
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}_machine2 = "
                                  button-off.service \
                                  machine2-startup.service \
                                  "
inherit systemd autotools

do_compile() {
}

do_install_prepend() {
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}${sysconfdir}/${MACHINE}/
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.d/
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}${bindir}/
    ln -s /usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc ${D}${bindir}/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
}

do_install_machine1() {
    install -m 0755 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine1/usr/bin/*.sh ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine1/lib/systemd/system/*.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
    install -m 0744 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine1/etc/machine1/startup ${D}${sysconfdir}/machine1/
    install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine1/etc/udev/rules.d/* ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/
}

do_install_machine2() {
    install -m 0755 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine2/usr/bin/*.sh ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine2/lib/systemd/system/*.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
    install -m 0744 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine2/etc/machine2/startup ${D}${sysconfdir}/machine2/
    install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine2/etc/udev/rules.d/* ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/
}

Recipe Whose Services Are Disabled on Boot:
SRC_URI_machine1 = "
                file://service1.service \
                file://machine1-service2.service \
               "
SRC_URI_machine2 =  "
                    file://service1.service \
                    file://machine2-service2.service \
                    "
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit systemd
inherit autotools

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
FILES_${PN} += "${bindir} ${systemd_unitdir}/system ${D}${prefix}/src/debug/${PN}/${PV}-${PR}/git "

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}_machine1 = "machine1-service2.service service1.service"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}_machine2 = "machine2-service2.service service1.service"

do_install_machine1() {
        install -d -m 0755 ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
        install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine1-service2.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
        install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/service1.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
}

do_install_machine2() {
        install -d -m 0755 ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
        install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/machine2-service2.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
        install -m 0644 -D ${WORKDIR}/service1.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
}


What is the value of systemd_unitdir? Can you successfully enable the services by hand after the system has booted?

I can successfully enable the service manually by using systemctl enable <service>. The value of systemd_unitdir is /lib/systemd
